# Secrets created using oc in Openshift not taking value after semicolon

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am creating secrets in OpenShift using oc as below :

```
oc create secret generic mysecret --from- 
literal=jdbc.mmi.driverClassName=something --from- 
literal=jdbc.mmi.userid=something --from-literal=jdbc.mmi.password=something  
-from-literal=jdbc.mmi.url=something;databaseName=somedatabasename
```

In the above command openShift is not taking value after semicolon  **;databaseName=somedatabasename**

How to handle such kind of value in openshift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quoting the value. An unquoted `;` terminates the command

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just one question is it a good idea to keep the database in the secrets in openshift